# Converting Unicode character to codepoint in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I have a module which was written in Python 3, and one of it's function is to convert a unicode character into codepoints (e.g.  to 127921 by using `ord(''`).

Now I need to convert this code to make it work on Python 2, but `ord()` doesn't work on Python 2 with non-ascii characters.

I have tried by using `''.encode('utf8')` or `''.encode('hex')`, but to no avail.

Looked into `__futures__` package, and it doesn't seem to help.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it in the simple way: check the `ord` manpage: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord: just UCS2 is supported in python2 (so codes below 65536).

Note: you should prefix with `u` the unicode strings.

You should calculate manually

```
to_decode = u''
code = ord(to_decode[0])
if code >= 0xd800 and code <= 0xdbff:
    # we have surrogates
    code = (code - 0xd800) * 1024 + (ord(to_decode[1]) - 0xdc00) +  + 0x010000
```

ADDENDUM: why?:

Original Unicode envisioned that a 16-bit coding was enough (this explain the merge of Han/Kana (Chinese/Japanese), and Korean special implementation). This gives code point from 0 to 65535, often encoded as UCS2.  Python 2 uses such encoding.

When it was noted that 16 bit were not enough, Unicode found a way to use more bits: using "Surrogates": encoding codes above 65535 using two "16bit characters" (10 bits in the first "code", but in 0xD800..0xDBFF, and 10 bits in second "code" put in 0xDC00..0xDFFF, and adding 65536 (this last point ensures that there is no double way to encode a character (and to expand further the unicode range).

UTF-16 is UCS2 plus interpretation of surrogates (as specified in Unicode). But python2 use UCS2. If you try with `len(to_decode)`, you get `2` (the two surrogate code points/UCS2 characters, and not `1` code point as in Python3).  The above code, use ordinary `ord` to get code point (with argument as `unicode` type and not `string` type), but if it find that the first character is surrogate, it translate it (without additional checks). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+10000_to_U+10FFFF explains the calculations.  Note: Unicode specify that surrogate codes will never be allocated as code points, so the above function should be safe also with plain UCS2.

You should probably adapt the code, to scan a string (some characters are put in one `unicode` (as python2 type) character and some as two.

I recommend to use Python3 when possible: they fixed unicode without workarounds (so error prone and more complex) like in python2 or other languages.

Comment: Why the down vote? I think I'm correct, so if you do not explain, I cannot improve.